# spyOn and mocking implementation to throw an exception marks the test as failed even if the test succeeds

Tags: typescript, jestjs, nestjs

I have a NestJS TypeScript application. In it, `MyService` uses `MyRepository`. I want to test that when an error in `myRepository.upsert(...)` happens, the `myService.doSomething()` processes the error as expected.

Full code example is below. So I simulate the error with `jest.spyOn` and `mockImplementation` as follows:

```typescript
jest.spyOn(myRepository, 'upsert').mockImplementation((myEntity: MyEntity) =>
    Promise.reject(new Error('SAVE FAILED'))
  )
```

Please note in the code below that `doSomething()` is neither rethrowing the error, nor throwing another error instead.

Then I make an expectation in the test. Everything works correctly, the error triggered by `upsert(...)` is cought and processed correctly by `myService.doSomething()`, the expectation in the test case succeeds and the test case finishes without throwing an error.

However Jest is marking `doSomething_failedUpdate` test as failed. Why? And how can I have the test marked as successful by Jest, given that my expectation succeeds and the test is not throwing any error?

Full code:

```typescript
export class MyResponse {
  // ...
  errorCode: number
}

// A database repository for CRUD operations:

@Injectable()
class MyRepository {
  // ...
  async upsert(myEntity: MyEntity): Promise<MyEntity> {
    // ...
  }
}

// A service using the repository:

@Injectable()
export class MyService {      
  constructor(
    private myRepository: MyRepository
  )
  
  async doSomething(): Promise<MyResponse> {  
    let response: MyResponse = new MyResponse()
      
    try {
      // ..
      await this.myRepository.upsert(myEntity)      
    } catch (error) {
      response.errorCode = 100
    }

    return response
  }
  
// The jest test:  
  
import { expect } from 'chai'
import { INestApplication } from '@nestjs/common'
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing'
// other imports here
  
describe('Test MyService.doSomething', () => {
  let appModuleFixture: TestingModule = null
  let app: INestApplication = null
  let myService: MyService = null
  let myRepository: MyRepository = null
  
  beforeEach(async () => {
    appModuleFixture = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [AppModule],
    }).compile()
  
    app = appModuleFixture.createNestApplication()
    app.useGlobalFilters(new DefaultExceptionFilter(), new MyExceptionFilter())
    await app.init()
  
    myRepository = appModuleFixture.get(MyRepository)
    myService = appModuleFixture.get(MyService)
  })
  
  afterEach(async () => {
    await app.close()
    jest.resetAllMocks()
  })
  
  // Other test here: 'doSomething_ok' ...

  it('doSomething_failedUpdate', async () => {
    // GIVEN:
    jest.spyOn(myRepository, 'upsert').mockImplementation((myEntity: MyEntity) =>
        Promise.reject(new Error('SAVE FAILED'))
      )
    
    // WHEN:
    let response = await myService.doSomething()
    
    // THEN:
    expect(response.errorCode).to.be.equal(100)
  })
})
```

Output from jest:

```
FAIL test/services/my.service.e2e-spec.ts (13.048 s)
  Test MyService.doSomething
    ✕ doSomething_failedUpdate (9490 ms)
    ○ skipped doSomething_ok

  ● Test MyService.doSomething › doSomething_failedUpdate

    SAVE FAILED

      448 |       .spyOn(myRepository, 'upsert')
      449 |       .mockImplementation((myEntity: MyEntity) =>
    > 450 |         Promise.reject(new Error('SAVE FAILED'))
          |                        ^
      451 |       )
      452 |
      453 |     // WHEN

      at MyRepository.<anonymous> (services/my.service.e2e-spec.ts:450:24)
      ...

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 skipped, 2 total
```

The test run command:

```shell
$ npx run ./node_modules/.bin/jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json  --runInBand -i test/services/my.service.e2e-spec.ts -t "doSomething_failedUpdate"
```

Comment: Can you add more of your test code?  You mention that `expect`s succeed but we can't see them.  Also, after your final `expect`, try adding a `console.log("Done");` and verify that you actually see it.  The failure might be coming after the test case itself has completed.

Comment: I did that (add a colsole.log after expectation) and it was printing it, then it stopped printing it - not sure why.

Comment: Well if we could see your test code maybe we could help :)

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out what was going on: in the catch block there is actually more code and that code was also calling the same `myRepository.upsert(...)` and it was failing this time too, which was not my intention when I mocked it. And the second failure (from within the catch block) was propagating and failing the test. My mistake was that I used `mockImplementation(...)`, when I should have used instead **`mockImplementationOnce(...)`**, so that the second call to `myRepository.upsert(...)` (from inside the catch block) does not fail too.

Comment: As a rule of thumb: if the code in the question doesn't actually contain the problem, you need to edit it or more likely just delete the whole thing. Please test you have a [mre] before posting, it's an important debugging step that may help you solve your own problem.